# Apache reverse proxy root with jboss

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, jboss

I just fixed my reverse proxy with apache to a jboss server, and finally it works I had to use AJP, not just reverse proxy because I had problems loggin in,

This is my server configuration which it doesnt make much sense to me, because when I was just using reverse proxy, on the proxypass I pointed to port 8080 to my jboss server, but here it is doing different. 
Anyways now it works perfect and I can log. All the css and js are diplayed, but when I go to www.mydomain.com I get the jboss root page, I want it to go to /catalogoBiologia instead, I was tweaking with proxypas and proxypassreverse but it is not working.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.mydomain.com
        ProxyRequests off
        ErrorLog logs/www.mydomain.com-error_log
        CustomLog logs/www.mydomain.com-access_log common

        JkMount /* ajp13_worker
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName reverse.mydomain.com
        ProxyPass /catalogoBiologia http://www.mydomain.com:80/
        ProxyPassReverse /catalogoBiologia http://www.mydomain.com:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a few smaller changes (Untested).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /www/catalogoBiologia
        ProxyRequests off
        ErrorLog logs/www.mydomain.com-error_log
        CustomLog logs/www.mydomain.com-access_log common

        JkMount /* ajp13_worker
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName reverse.mydomain.com
        ProxyPass / http://www.mydomain.com:80/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://www.mydomain.com:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

I think this will forward `http://reverse.mydomain.com/` to `http://www.mydomain.com/`, and since I changed the `DocumentRoot` of `www.mydomain.com` to `/www/catalogoBiologia` this will be the default location of `www.mydomain.com`.

Of course this is only valid if you want to change the document root, but I kind of get the impression that you want `http://www.mydomain.com/` to open up the `catalogoBiologia` stuff by default.

As I said, I have not tested this myself, but it might give you a few pointers and help you forward.

PS: `/www/catalogoBiologia` should of course match your path.